# Can anyone identify these insects in my rose bud?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, insects, roses

What are these?[image: insects on rose bud]
Just noticed them - wondering if they are bad for the plant or my health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rose aphids (Macrosiphum rosae). The two backwards-facing tube are black, which  confirms identification.

Not good for roses.

They carry viruses from plant to plant, and a large number on a rosebud will stop the flower forming.

What to do? search this forum for "rose aphids". If you have time you can rub them off with gloves into a bucket, natural predators can sometimes (only sometimes) keep the population low.

Not a health problem for humans - but the treatments can be.